# Boot Configure Pin Causing Failure

Tags: boot-configure

I have a boot configure pin which I am also using for UART communications.  If this pin is connected and pulled up during boot it will cause boot failures.  Right now I am pulling it up just slightly too soon and all boots are failing.

The pin in question forms a UART connection between the booting module and my MC but in-between is a logic level shifter IC ([TXS0108EPWR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0108e.pdf)).  This IC has an enable pin and when this is low the boot-config pin is in a high impendence state (desired).

The enable pin is connected to the booting module's VDD_EXT (denoted by #2 in the timing image below).  The problem is there isn't enough lag between steps 2 and 3 so all boots are failing.

I apply power to the module, toggle the power key, 30ms later VDD_EXT becomes high which enables the bridge IC pulling the boot configure pin high.  According to the timing diagram I need to add about 200ms of lag here.  Is there a way to do so but still keep VDD_EXT as the bridge IC's enable connection?  Would adding a capacitor on the OE line accomplish this?

[image]
[image: circuit]

Answer (score 2):

Add a capacitor in parallel to resistor R404 to delay the OE signal. Start with a 20uF cap and increase to desired delay time. The actual voltage to make OE active is 0.65 x VDD_EXT, so without knowing VDD_EXT the capacitor size cannot be calculated.

Comment: VDD_EXT is 1.8V